# PHP7 Curl and OpenSSL extensions does not work with Apache 2 Handler on Windows

Tags: windows, curl, openssl, apache2, php-7

Having problem to initilize curl and openssl extensions from PHP7 in Apache2.2 module handler mode.

If I use FCGI mode, curl and openssl from PHP7 work just fine and I can see them in phpinfo page.

I have checked dependencies of curl and openssl php extensions and saw that they dynamically link to libssh2.dll. Then have tried to add libssh2.dll to path, system path but that still does not work.

So guess that somehow Apache2.2 is maybe an issue as curl and openssl extensions from PHP7 work fine when started in FCGI mode. Is there a way to check that with ollydbg or windbg?

Answer (score 3):

You must overwrite this files: libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in apache/bin directory, get this files from your php7/ directory

http://php.net/manual/es/openssl.installation.php

Comment: This is a correct answer.
Also, the problem doesn't relate to apache 2.2 only, it happens on all apache2 versions.

Comment: You may also need to do the same for `libssh2.dll`. That was the case in my own experience.

Answer (score 3):

Try to update Apache to a latest stable. It helped me to solve the problem having PHP 7.0.6RC1 and Apache 2.4.4 (updated to 2.4.20).